# Flash SimpleButton sticks in over state?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm working on a Flash project using ActionScript 3.

Our interface switches between different modes by adding and removing the direct children of the main stage--we call these scenes.

The problem I've encountered is this: One of these scenes has a SimpleButton (flash.display.SimpleButton) with distinct up and over states. When I mouseover a button, it goes to the over state as expected. But if the application automatically switches to a new scene (in this case, a video finishes and the app moves on) and then the user navigates back (causing the original scene to be re-added), the button stays in the over state until I mouse back in and then out again. I'd like to be able to force that button back into its up state.

I've tried setting b.overState = b.upState, but then there's no appearance change on subsequent rollovers. I've also tried dispatching a ROLL_OUT event to the button object, but that doesn't do anything either.

Any ideas other than implementing something from scratch that exposes a way to force a state change?

Comment: Total guess so not worth an answer, but have you tried toggling it's enabled property to false and then back to true?

Comment: @shanethehat: I actually did try that earlier this morning. No luck. Thanks. :)

Comment: Just curious, have you set the `hitTestState` property to the same `DisplayObject` as your overState?

Comment: @Peter: Indeed it is. The stuck state issue seems to be pretty simply that it never registeres a roll out since the button is removed from the display list while the mouse is still over it.

Comment: Have you tried dispatching the ROLL_OUT on the button after it gets added back to the display list?

Comment: Sounds like when you roll over and then out again, it fixes the problem so that's what I would do, but programmatically it. eg. `myButton.dispatch()` a `MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER` followed by a `MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT` I realize that's a hack and not a fix, but it's what I have.

Comment: create a remover for the button on Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, and then "add" the button back in(a new button) manually on Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE or a similar event to bring the button back into it's default state (ie, make a new button with the same stuff in it). Or do it manually by calling functions, though this should work.

Comment: I have **exactly** the same problem. Did you solve it or make work-around?

Answer (score 1):

here is what I had to do:

```
// store ref to normal over state
var overState = myBtn.overState;

// since we cant change the state, change the over state's asset to the up state
myBtn.overState = myBtn.upState;

// since we want the state to change on mouse over, reset the overstate once it rolled over again
myBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, function(e){
    myBtn.overState = overState;
})
```

it's not too pretty, but it works. in my case, i fire this swapping logic when i render the buttons parent to the display list. if you are using scene's you could probably do it once the scene changes back to the one with your button.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem:
Panel has buttons. The click button switches window. When panel restored, it has the button in wrong state.
I can't fix my problem with your issue because panel has many different buttons.

**Bug**: ROLL_OUT happens AFTER(!) my panel removed from stage. This is the real reason why the button can't normal restored state.

**Bug fix (work around)**:
You should generate ROLL_OUT event BEFORE(!) parent object will be removed from stage. The easy way to do this is a create empty sprite and overlap panel, such as:

Step 1:

```
  var overlay:Sprite = new Sprite();
  overlay.graphics.beginFill( 0x000000, .5 );
  overlay.graphics.drawRect( 0, 0,  _sprite.width, _sprite.height );
  overlay.graphics.endFill();
  overlay.x = _sprite.x;
  overlay.y = _sprite.y;
  overlay.name = "TRICK";
  addChild(overlay); // The top element overlay is override the buttons and it’s automatically generated event ROLL_OUT
```

Step 2:
If window with panel and buttons is restored then remove overlay:

```
  var overlay:Sprite = this.getChildByName("TRICK") as Sprite;
  if (overlay) removeChild(overlay);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with some menus, each menu was removed from the display list before the new one was added.

After many attempts to find a work around the best one I found was to keep it them on the display list and just set their visibility to false.

```
function setMenu(newMenu:Sprite = null):void
{
    menuA.visible = menuB.visible = menuC.visible = false;
    if(newMenu)
    {
        newMenu.visible = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to replace the `simpleButton` with a `MovieClip`, but if you want a real solution you should write a bug report to Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`MOUSE_OVER`** and **`MOUSE_OUT`** instead.
`ROLL_OVER` and `ROLL_OUT` do not propagate to child objects.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and after reading gthmb's answer this is what I did. I set hitTestState to the same as overState during init (previously it was the same as upState), and:

```
public static function ResetButton(b:SimpleButton):void
{
   b.overState = b.upState;
   b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, RestoreButton);
}

private static function RestoreButton(e:Event):void
{
   e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, RestoreButton);
   e.target.overState = e.target.hitTestState;
}
```

So for each problematic button, just add `ResetButton(e.target as SimpleButton);` in  their CLICK event listener. Don't use it on every button though, because then when you click it, if the scene doesn't change the button won't go back to the over state but to the up state. Apply it to one of the ordinary buttons if you don't know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily fixed if you leave the SimpleButton on the stage but you set visible = false; However if you want to remove it from the stage and make sure the button has the event mouse_out dispatched on it here is how I suggest you do it:

To set the SimpleButton back to the mouse out state I suggest a few seconds later assuming the user house moused out, you may remove it from the stage, see the following example:

```
_removeTimer = new Timer(2000);
_removeTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, _onRemove);

function _onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
            e.stopPropagation();
            //hide button for now
            _button.visible = false;
            //move button to trigger mouse event
            _button.x = 0;
            _button.y = 0;
            e.updateAfterEvent();
            e.stopPropagation();
            //set timer to remove the button later
            _removeTimer.start();

}

function _onRemove(e:Event):void{
            _removeTimer.stop();
            _button.parent.removeChild(_button);
            //reset button to original coordinates
            _button.x = 100;
            _button.y = 300;
}
```