# Change state of SimpleButton

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm using standart SimpleButton in my popup windows. The problem is when I closing popup by clicking SimpleButton, the next time popup appears, that SimpleButton still holds "MouseOver" state. It switch back to normal only if I move the cursor over and out.
I've tried to make "gotoAndStop", but SimpleButton is not a MovieClip.
I've tried to fire the MouseOut and RollOut events manually, but it still no luck.
What can be done?

Comment: See **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944531/flash-simplebutton-sticks-in-over-state)**

Comment: I don't bother with SimpleButton and find it much easier just to create a custom class extending a Sprite that does all the SimpleButton does and more, since it extends Sprite it can have children, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known "bug" and afaik there is no real workaround for it.

I stopped using SimpleButton since sooner or later you will want to use some kind of custom behaviour for it anyway. (Slowly fade in, some flash effect or whatever).

Thus the easiest way is to convert the buttons to movieclips with frame labels and then do `gotoAndPlay("over_in")` or `gotoAndPlay("over")` or whatever you want to do.

Think I have used a workaround by playing some short movieclip on the "over state" that spans for 10 frames or so and then is deleted when it is done. But can't remember if that was in AS2 or AS3. I know that I started using the "labeled movieclip solution" and haven't really used anything else since then.

Comment: The best part about movieclips and to improve on my answer is that there are lots of ways of automating this process. You could add a component that receives data for the bg, the text, the border etc. Or you could make it possible to create a "template button" through jsfl script. That already has the labels created :)